What are the roles of $x$ and $y$ in the functional equation: $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$ for all $x,y$ in R?
I am slightly confused by the roles of input variables for certain functional equations. Kinda new to this study of functions.
Knowing the role of variables in standard equations such as $ax+by-c=0$, coming to functional equations is a little confusing.
I understand this function is a function of 1 variable (not 2) where the form is $f(x)=cx$.
When we plug the solution back into the equation, we apply $f$ to $x$ and $y$. At this point I'm thinking, we don't necessarily care what the variables are named, as long as $x$ and $y$ are not the same real number. Is this correct?
Finally, can I visually see this property play out by picking arbitrary values for $f$, then apply the sums, from its graph?
Thanks!

Important to realize the equation $f(x+y) = f(x) +f(y)$ has nothing to do with the definition of $f$.  $f(x+y)= f(x) +f(y)$ simply means $f(3+4) = f(3) + f(4)$ and if we replace $3$ with any other value and $4$ with any other value we'd get $f(a+b) = f(a)+f(b)$.  And there is NO requirement that $x\ne y$.  We hav $f(6) = f(3+3)=f(3)+f(3)=2f(3)$.  Also not that $f(7) = f(0)+f(7)=f(1)+f(6)=f(3)+(4) =f(\pi) + f(7-\pi)=f(-27.3) + f(34.3)$ etc.  Actually noting $f(x)=f(0)+f(x)$ and $f(2x)=2f(x)$ might give you hint how to start.

The mapping $u\mapsto f(u)$ is a function of one variable. On the other hand the mappings $(x,y)\mapsto f(x+y)$ and $(x,y)\mapsto f(x)+f(y)$ are functions of two variables. There is no need to require $x\neq y.$ The equation means that these two functions innteo variables coincide.

Actually, unless you assume the function is continuous you can not know that $f(x)=cx$ for some:  But you can prove that $f(x)=cx$ for all $x\in \mathbb Q$.  (Hint:  Consider that for $n\in \mathbb N$ we have $n=1+1+1+..... + 1$ and $\frac 1n + \frac 1n + \frac 1n+...... + \frac 1n=1$.)

No where in the question is there any mention of any function with 2 variables (and I'm a little perplexed as to why so many comments are talking of them).  When we say $f(x+y)$ we meant that $x+y$ is a single value $f(x+y)$ the output of that single value.  If $x+y = m$ then $f(x+y) = f(m)$.  If $x=3$ and $y=5$ then $f(x+y)=f(3+5)=f(8)$. That's all thats going on.  $x+y$ has to equal something and as $f$ maps all real values to other real values it must map $x+y$ to somewhere.  That somewhere is $f(x+y)$.

@fleablood So the equation itself has nothing to do with the definition of f, I find that interesting. So the inputs in the equation just represent arbitrary values from the Reals. I too am a bit confused by the responses as I've never mentioned multivariable functions.

It's a function that has the property that for any $a,b$ (and they can be any real value.  If $a + b =m$ (and $m$ can be anything) we will always have $f(m)=f(a) + f(b)$.  From that, I'm telling you and giving you a problem to solve, that the exist some real constant $c$ and, for every $x\in \mathbb Q$ the $f$ will map $x\mapsto cx$.... how can you prove that? .......  (Hint: what is $f(0)$?  Is there anyway to know what $f(1)$ is? [Answer:... no....]  If we decide to label $f(1)=k$ then .... what happens)

I guess what I don't understand about you question is when you say: "I understand this function is a function of 1 variable (not 2) where the form is f(x)=cx."  How do you know that? Were you told that?

Oops I did mention 2 variables in my question, my bad. I was just a little confused with the definition of f and how it relates to the equation. I assumed f was differentiable. When you say f(1) equals some constant, did you derive that from the equation itself or just set f(1) = some kind. @fleablood
